# How to enable file logging in spring boot?

Tags: logging, spring-boot-actuator

Console log is by default activated in spring boot. I like to log to file, e.g. /var/log/mylog.log.

How to enable file logging in spring boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Spring Boot documentation you have to enable file logging by setting a property in your application configuration (application.properties / application.yaml / etc.).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output

> By default, Spring Boot logs only to the console and does not write log files. If you want to write log files in addition to the console output, you need to set a logging.file or logging.path property (for example, in your application.properties).

For example in application.properties:

`logging.file=myFile`

Writes to the specified log file. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.

`logging.path=/var/log`

Writes spring.log to the specified directory. Names can be an exact location or relative to the current directory.